# YouTube Javascript API loadVideoByID bug in Internet Explorer

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

Hopefully somebody can verify this or shed some insight.

The most basic use of player.loadVideoByID() method seems not to be working in IE.

I have deployed the google getting started sample code from:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

to my site to illustrate the issue.

You can use this link and view the source to easily see it in action.

http://www.fuhshnizzle.com/YT.html

You will also note that the sample which autoplays in chrome, ff & safari merely shows the play icon in IE.
So that is really 2 bugs.

No autoplay and loadVideoByID() is tossing an exception in all flavors of IE.

I have wrapped the loadVideoByID() method  call in a try catch and you can see it is no longer working in IE but is fine in chrome, ff & safari.

I would imagine this is affecting EVERY IE YT API app that uses this method call and therefore should be a major priority for google/YouTube team. Since stackoverflow has the best developer response times I thought I would reach out for support here.

Thanks very much!